# How to get info from java code that the WebLogic AdminConsole is "Locked for Edit"?

Tags: java, weblogic, administration

Anyone know the way how to get info that the WebLogic AdminConsole is locked for edit?
Maybe some MBean...
I don't know what else :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is using [WLST](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/config_scripting/using_WLST.html#1056953) to connect to a running admin console and printing out status.

Try the [WLST Edit commands](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/config_scripting/reference.html#1179175) to see if there is one that works for you, I can see `cancelEdit` and `saveEdit` commands, but not one to specifically check if the Admin console is locked for editing.

Answer (score 0):

You want to know how to get that information programmatically or from weblogic admin UI?

Comment: No! Not from UI,maybe from JMX.